# Rails - Invalid Authenticity Token After Deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

We're using EngineYard Cloud to deploy our Ruby on Rails application.  We are running Rails v2.3.3.

EngineYard Cloud deploys to AWS instances in a manner similar to Capistrano.  After each deploy, we're running into Invalid Authenticity Token errors.  Specifically, any user that has previously visited our application and then visits after the deploy and then tries to submit a form gets an invalid authenticity token error.  This error persists until they reset their cookies for the site.  After they reset their cookies, the site works as expected with no errors.

We are using ActiveRecord's session store and sessions are being saved to the database.

This is the error we are seeing:

> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
>     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/request_forgery_protection.rb:79:in `verify_authenticity_token'

The session object is nil after the deploy, however, the session data still persists in the database and the session ID cookie still exists:

> Session:
>
> - session id: nil
> - data: nil

We haven't been able to explain this one.  Any thoughts on what could be the root cause?

Thanks for any suggestions!

---

EDIT: Just to update on this, we've been able to isolate an example of the error.

1) User loads form
2) Code is updated on server
3) User submits form
** Invalid Authenticity Token error occurs

It seems that when the environment changes, Rails is unable to handle this with the authenticity token.

We've tried several steps to resolve:

- Resetting the session
- Deleting the session cookie (both in JavaScript and Rails)
- Wiping the session table in the database after deploying code

Nothing works.  The only thing that works is having the user clear their cookies client-side.

(We've been Googling (even tried Binging!) for answers, but no dice.  This seems to be a similar related issue: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=21479)

Also: initially we thought this was isolated to our deployment to EngineYard, but we've also been able to reproduce it on our development server that we deploy to via Capistrano.

Any thoughts would be gratefully accepted.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have time to look up the answer right now, but you're going to want to go into the Rails source and see exactly how the auth token is generated. It may be that the server restart is changing a value that's used to seed that token.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**ANSWER:**  After extensive work by EngineYard (they're awesome!) they were able to diagnose the issue.  The root cause of this issue is a bug with mongrel clusters.  Mongrel doesn't seem to see the first post request after being started.  EngineYard did extensive work to diagnose this:

> There doesn't appear to be anything in your code causing the issue and I have found people outside of our environment that have experienced the bug as well (http://www.thought-scope.com/2009/07/mongrelcluster-rails-23x-bad-post.html). I suppose a lot of people don't see it because the first request to a site generally isn't a post or they chalk it up to flukes.
>
> [There is a potential workaround using CURL.]  The curl work around would do a simple GET request to each of your mongrels on the server to prime them so to speak. You could do this with capistrano, but that won't work if you deploy via the dashboard. You can find a short section on deploy hooks we have built into the infrastructure here: 
>   https://cloud-support.engineyard.com/faqs/overview/getting-started-with-engine-yard-cloud
>
> Adding a simple run curl http://localhost:500x > /dev/null should work (where x is the port you have 5000-50005 on your current setup).

We have addressed the issue by switching our stack from Mongrel to Passenger, but apparently, a fix for Mongrel is in the works.  Hopefully, this helps someone who sees this same strange issue.

Comment: I just switched from Mongrel to Passenger and this fixed 3 hair-pulling issues.

Answer (score 9):

The authenticity token is a hidden field on the form that rails checks when the form is submitted to ensure that the post data is coming from a live session.

It is there as a security measure to prevent malicious people from using a form submit on their site to say a delete action on someones account.

You can turn it off on your whole app by adding this to `config/environment.rb`

```
config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
```

You can turn it off a single controller using

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

or turn it on

```
protect_from_forgery :except => :index
```

check out the [ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection::ClassMethods](http://caboo.se/doc/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html) docs for more details

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Yes, we understand what the token does and how to disable it completely.  We'd like to be able to use it if we can solve why it breaks upon each deploy.

Comment: This tip provides a nice workaround for this problem.  I'm facing the same issue with Amazon EC2.  What's the (secure) long-term solution?

Comment: This is not a solution. It’s an insecure workaround.

Comment: hi @EricWalker, i am facing a similar issue for ec2, can you share what fix you implemented?

Comment: @opensource-developer I ran into this sometime in or before 2010, and I don't remember what I did.  As @rubiii mentions, it's insecure to turn off forgery protection.  Looking at the original question, it looks like there's something bad happening when the old cookie is loaded.  So I wonder whether changing the cookie base might fix it, by changing the `key` value here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13778235/61048.

Comment: HI @EricWalker, thanks for your reply, actually, in my case i fixed it by appending port to the `Host` header parameter in `Nginx`.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the secret key used for authentication is changing when you redeploy, invalidating all existing sessions.

Do you have the configuration parameter `config.action_controller.session` set anywhere, and if you do, is there anything which would cause it to change when you redeploy?

One of my apps has it configured in `config/environment.rb`, and a more recent one (generated with Rails 2.3) has it set in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`. The setting looks like:

```
config.action_controller.session = {
    :secret      => 'long-string-of-hex-digits'
  }
```

If you don't have this configured for some reason, `rake secret` will generate a key for you, which can then be inserted into your configuration.

(If it is — and it's not being changed by your deployment processes — then I have no idea what's going on.)

Comment: hm.  Really interesting thought.  I'll certainly look into this in more detail and see what I can find out about whether the secret key could be changing on each deploy.

Answer (score 1):

If it would only be there for mongrels! I'm getting the exact same error on passenger as well (user loads form, deploy, submit -> invalid authenticity token). It'd be interesting to know how you solved the issue by switching to passenger? Any further hints are highly welcome. I'll have a closer look as well...

Cheers!

Comment: ok, my fault. as stated in http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/3/16/rails-2-3-templates-engines-rack-metal-much-more one should also update passenger in order to work with rails 2.3.x (I was still using passenger 2.0.3). After updating (to 2.2.5 as is) it works just fine. cheers!

Comment: Glad you got it working!  With Passenger and Rails 2.3.x, this issue seems to be completely resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Have encountered this same problem with Rails 2.3 and a Mongrel cluster where the session secret is definitely set in the session initializer.  The problem occured even after clearing the client cookies on the client.

However the suggestion of doing a curl get request across all the mongrels after they restart appears to work - thank goodness someone figured this out because it appears to be pretty darned obscure.

The only added info I can supply we are using Apache mod_proxy_balancer along with https in front of our Mongrels, however this problem was occuring before we turned on SSL.  Is anyone seeing this with haproxy as the balancer instead of Apache?

Answer (score 1):

This solved this issue for me :-) :-) :-)

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/4690-mongrel-doesnt-work-with-rails-238#ticket-4690-37 Posted by Mike Bethany
August 30th, 2010 @ 06:43 PM.

Comment: Try to include the main idea in your post. The other site can go down.

Answer (score 0):

I've never gone to any length to figure out the details, but for me, this is a client-side data rot issue.  If I've been messing around with the way I store my sessions (and therefore, my authorization details,) I get this error from time to time.  Clearing out the private browser data; cookies, authenticated sessions, the works, has always solved it for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am might be too late for answering this but still writing here in case any of the above solution doesn't work try to check you redis server installed correctly and It service is working.

Here are the command to install and start the redis service

```
brew install redis
brew services info redis
brew services start redis
```