# Rails: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken appears when changing to active_record_store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, session-store

I just changed my session_store to active_record_store. I did the rake command for db:sessions:create and db:migration, but now I get the following issue, as soon as I try to log in.

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

How to solve this issue?

Markus

Comment: Yes! I guess the active record store is working...

Comment: what rails version are you using and how are you authenticating your users? Gem/etc.

Comment: Im using rails 3, with the restful authentication plugin...

Comment: have you seen this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201901/rails-invalid-authenticity-token-after-deploy ?

Comment: I saw it, but It sould do without changing to Passenger... (I don't want to do that change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a rather stupid one, but you have to know it...

I had to restart not only the server but also my browser to have the new authenticity token!

Now it works perfectly...

Answer (score 1):

Any changes in the configuration of a rails app requires restarting the server to see the changes.

Comment: ok, so you restarted the server and now you are getting the error?