# Rename session cookies in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, ruby-on-rails-3.1, session-cookies, rack

since I'd like the session cookie to reflect the url and not the app name, I'd like to rename the cookies..

The current session cookie name is called `_APPNAME_session`

is there a way to rename it to `_somethingelse_session`?

I see the name of it when I do

```
curl -i <appurl>
```

I see

```
set_cookie = _APPNAME_session=....
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- Rails >= 6.0.0, in config/application.rb, add the following line:

  ```
  config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_somethingelse_session'
  ```
- Rails >= 5.0.0, in config/initializers/session_store.rb, set/change the following line:

  ```
  Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_somethingelse_session'
  ```
- Rails < 5.0.0, in config/initializers/session_store.rb, set/change the following line:

  ```
  <APPNAME>::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_somethingelse_session'
  ```

Comment: If your using activerecord sesion store you can just write this: `<APPNAME>::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => "_somethingelse_session"`

Comment: if you want you can also set `:expire_after`, `secure:`, and `httponly:` while your at it.
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.6/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html